# Google Maps API driving times for specific dates and times

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Does google maps have an API that will estimate driving times for a specific dates and times?

Comment: I'm not aware of any APIs which will estimate driving time given arbitrary dates or times.

Answer (score 0):

This is Distancematrix 
readmore here Javascript API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

DEMO JAVASCRIPT API: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix

WEB SERVICE
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/